# How to cast a SwigPyObject to ctypes void*

Tags: python, c++, c, swig, ctypes

I have a python, ctypes wrapped function to a C API taking a void* parameter for a class X, e.g.
C:

```
myFunc(void* aXHandle); //where X is a class, of class X.
```

For the class X, I have access to a swigged API and can get the myX.this, which is of type SwigPyObject.

How do I cast this so I can call my C-API function using ctypes and using a ctypes c_void_p as an argument?
In Python, I thought something like: 
    aXObjectThis = myX.this

```
myHandle = cast(aXObjectThis, c_void_p)
```

but that does not work; getting "wrong type in argument 1"

Answer (score 3):

The `__int__` method of `SwigPyObject` is handled by `SwigPyObject_long`, defined in [pyrun.swg](http://sourceforge.net/p/swig/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Lib/python/pyrun.swg). It returns `PyLong_FromVoidPtr(v->ptr)`, so you should be able to use the following:

```
myHandle = c_void_p(int(myX.this))
```

More conveniently ctypes looks for an `_as_parameter_` attribute. You could set this on the instance or as a property:

```
type(myX)._as_parameter_ = property(
    lambda self: c_void_p(int(self.this)))
```

The simply call `myFunc(myX)`.

Comment: Thanks! This seem to save some typing! Nice